# Istio automatic sidecar-injection for envoy proxy failing 1.2.3

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

Istio successfully installed and automatic Sidecar injection enabled on an application's namespace (via label and mutatingwebhook).

Application then deployed on this namespace and the pods are given the annotation of:
sidecar.istio.io/status:{"version":"versionhash","initContainers":null,"containers":null,"volumes":null,"imagePullSecrets":null}

This seems to suggest a misconfiguration of istio-sidecar injector, as I would expect it to have valid values for these parameters, however all values being used are out of the box Istio. What could cause this?

I am running on bare-metal/VM Kubernetes v1.15 with Istio deployed from the 1.2.3 helm charts (istio-init and then istio).

More information on my configuration/troubleshooting is available on 
https://discuss.istio.io/t/troubleshooting-istio-sidecar-injector-1-2-3/3688

Comment: Share details on your infrastructure, how did you deploy Istio and how injection was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was because I was missing the files/injection-template.yaml from my istio helm install directory, which is referenced in the sidecar-injection-configmap.yaml, so it was missing the template to inject the pods with, hence the null values.